# Shiny: if else statement in server.R has unexpected symbol

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with the following code in R that throws an 'unexpected symbol' error when it is evaluated in my shiny app.

```
output$CHOresult <- renderText({
  CHOdiff = CHOdiff(CHOsum = input$mass, CHOgoal = input$height)

  if      (CHOdiff <=  0.05) info = "<span style='color: green'>you do not need to add more carbohydrate.</span>"
  else    (CHOdiff > 0.05)   info = "<span style='color: red'>please add more carbohydrate.</span>"

  paste0("The carbohydrate in this meal is ", "<code>", round(CHOdiff, 2), "</code>", "grams away from the goal,", info)
})
```

The error message implies that the error occurs at the second `info`:

```
Error in source(file, ..., keep.source = TRUE, encoding = checkEncoding(file)) : 
  unexpected symbol
253:   if      (CHOdiff <=  0.05) info = "<span style='color: green'>you do not need to add more carbohydrate.</span>"
254:   else    (CHOdiff > 0.05)   info
                                  ^
```

I thought my if else statement was valid. Apparently it is not. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try something like [pseudocode]  `info <- ifelse(Chodiff <= 0.05, optiona,optionb)`